# Is CircleWithPrivateDataFields a class and c it's object in this method?

Tags: oop

```
  public static void printAreas(CircleWithPrivateDataFields c, int times)

     {
     System.out.println("Radius \t\tArea");
     while (times >= 1) {
     System.out.println(c.getRadius() + "\t\t" + c.getArea());
     c.setRadius(c.getRadius() + 1);
     times——;
     }
```

// CircleWithPrivateDataFields is a class. But in this method,as an 
  argument,is it a class or an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void printAreas(CircleWithPrivateDataFields c, int times)
```

this mean that printAreas function require 2 arguments. First argument is an instance of class *CircleWithPrivateDataFields* and is called *c*, second argument is primitive integer and is called *times*

So yes, CircleWithPrivateDataFields is class (or interface) and c is object (instance of class CircleWithPrivateDataFields).

*Send my regards to your teacher and good luck at exam :)*